# Cauchy problem for nolinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem:**

Find the solution of the following Cauchy problem
$$
u_{ttxx}(x,t) = (u_{tt}(x,t))^2 \quad \quad (1)
$$

$$
u(x, 0) = \phi_1(x) \quad
u_t(x, 0) = \phi_2(x)
$$
$$
u_{tt}(x, 0) = \phi_3(x) \quad
u_{ttt}(x, 0) = \phi_4(x)
$$

I was able to express the general solution in terms of Weierstrass elliptic function.

**Explanation:**

Let's set $w(x,t) = u_{tt}(x,t)$. Then from eq. (1)
$$
w_{xx}(x,t) = (w(x,t))^2 \quad \quad (2)
$$
Multiply lhs and rhs by $w_x(x,t)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{2} w_x^2 \right] = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{3}w(x,t)^3\right]
$$
Consequently,
$$
w_x(x,t)^2 = \frac{2}{3}w(x,t)^3 + C(t)
$$
Let's define a function $\wp(x)$ such that
$$
\left(\frac{d \wp}{d x}\right)^2 = 4 \wp(x)^3 + \bar{C}(t)
$$
where $\bar{C}(t) = 36 C(t)$, $t$ is fixed.
The general solution of this equation is the Weierstrass elliptic function (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions)) which can be found as the inverse of elliptic integral
$$
\int^\infty_{z}\frac{ds}{\sqrt{4s^3 + \bar{C}(t)}} = x, \quad z = \wp(x)
$$
Now setting $\bar{C}$ runs over time we will have the family of elliptic functions $\wp(x,t)$.
Obviously, $w(x,t) := 6 \wp(x,t)$ satisfies eq.(2).
So, the general solution of eq.(1) will have a form
$$
u(x,t) = \iint w(x,t) dt^2 + C_1(x)t+C_2(x) 
$$

Further steps for solving initial-value problem seem to be complicated.

**Question:**

The question is how to solve the original problem.

Comment: So your question is? Find the solution or differentiate it?