# Find the general solution of $u_{ttxx}(x,t)=(u_{tt}(t,x))^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the equation $$u_{ttxx}(x,t)=(u_{tt}(t,x))^2$$
Let set $v(x,t)=u_{tt}(x,t)$. Then $$v_{xx}(x,t)=(v(x,t))^2$$ What should I do next? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken the last differential equation can be solved in terms of weierstrass elliptic functions

Comment: Your last equation is now an ODE.. Multiply both sides by $v_{x}$ and integrate (remember your implicit differentiation).

Comment: After multiplying both sides by v{x} we obtain $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{2} v_x^2 \right] = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{3}v(x,t)^3\right]$ Is that right? Sadly, but i don't understand how to integrate this.

Comment: @Roman get's me something like, $\frac12 v_x^2(x,t)=\frac13 v^3(x,t)+\phi_0(t)$ . But yet again as you say, even this is hard to integrate.

$$\int{\frac{\partial{\left(v(x,t)\right)}}{\sqrt{\frac23 v^3(x,t)+\phi_0(t)}}}=\pm x+\lambda(t)$$

Comment: @tired You not mistaken. My examiner said thats right. But he didn't explain how to do it. What should I read to understand this? Will someone show me an identic example?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314388/cauchy-problem-for-nolinear-pde ?